# VBA: Grabbing a Cell Value dependant on its colour

Tags: vba, excel

So I have the following VBA code:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long

Dim datax As Range
Dim xcolor As Long

xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = datax.Select
    End If
Next datax

End Function
```

This code loops through the range given andsearches for a specific background colour. It then grabs the valu eof that colour and places it into the selected cell.

My problem is this only works if the data with the correct background colour is a number and not text.

Any ideas on why it cant grab the text from the cell?

It just displays #VALUE! if its text at the moment.

Comment: yes, you defined your `Function CountCcolor as Long`, so it accept numbers only.

Comment: I have also tried datax.Text  - but no luck

Comment: you can't, cause your `CountCcolor' is defined as `Long`

Comment: @ShaiRado - Cant believe i didnt notice that! I changed this code form counting the amount of background colour so forgot to change that bit! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
CountCcolor is defined as Long
```

Code should be,

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As String

Dim datax As Range
Dim xcolor As Long

xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
    CountCcolor = datax.Select
End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Thanks to @Shai Rado for noticing